# serve static file when response status 404 HAproxy

Tags: haproxy

I want to serve a static file like `errorfile` when the response status is 500. I have to use this config in the backend section.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the HAProxy documentation but could not immediately find a configuration setting for this. But why do you want HAProxy to catch this error and return a custom HTML page? Your backend web server allows having custom error pages for code 404 and 500.

**Edit:**
So I checked the documentation a bit more and although I haven't tested it (yet), we can perhaps try the following code in the frontend/listen/backend statement:

```
acl error_codes -m beg "HTTP/1.0 500"
acl error_codes -m beg "HTTP/1.0 404"
http-response allow redirect location http://example.com/errors/404.html if error_codes
```

Comment: I want to have the same error response in all the cases. servers might return a different response.

Comment: Servers might also return different web pages. The same way you sync your website across all servers, you can also sync the error pages across all webservers.

Comment: there are some servers that I cannot sync with(3rd part servers).

Comment: So your load balancer balances traffic with X servers, a small portion of which are third-party servers. But they must host the same web content? Then how do you sync the web content?

Comment: I use it more as a proxy than load balancing.

Comment: Okay, I edited my response.

Comment: but this will return 3** status and I do not want an extra request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82072/discussion-between-tom-and-peeyush-pathak).